# what Graphical DSP programming tools are there for ASIO4ALL?

Tags: audio

Many years ago I had a PCI sound card (I think it was some kind of SoundBlaster but not sure, this was maybe 15 years ago) with a 5 1/4 disk sized front panel with various ins and out.

I remember using ASIO4All but there was also a graphical component where I could program the DSP directly by creating a visual circuit and add effects and other features, and I used this to create a multitrack studio with talkback capabilities to the artists.

But I can't for the life of me remember what it was, or find anything similar on the webs.

is the 10k DSP chip still a thing? If not, what is the modern-day equivalent, and is the visual programming still available for it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ASIO4ALL](https://www.asio4all.org/index.php/project/) is a hardware independent low latency ASIO driver for WDM audio devices. As being a (wrapper) driver it does not support programming other but change of settings (device/channels selection, bit depth, sample rate, I/O buffers (latency)) through control software.

Regarding DSP programming tools, could you mean Creative/SoundBlaster specific [kxproject](https://github.com/kxproject) driver/software?

Edit 1:

Creative/SoundBlaster DSP chips are listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_Blaster).

There are also software based methods as well as like [EqualizerAPO](https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/)  (system-wide equalizer for Windows) which lets you route channels, EQ filtering, convolution etc..

Comment: Thank you so much! It was indeed the SB Audigy and KXproject, which sadly doesn't seem to be active these days.